# Body difference of D90 and D7100

Tags: body, nikon-d90, nikon-d7100

I had a D90 for many years and sold it for a D7100. However the D7100 body looks like it's made lightly or cheaper than the D90, is that so? The feel of the D90 was solid with hard plastic but with the D7100 it seems the plastic of the body and even the charger is cheaper. Is that true? I'm thinking I was ripped off.

Comment: You are worried about the battery charger construction?

Comment: @dpollitt no, just the body of the camera plus charger.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the battery charger.  My Canon 5D Mark iii is very solidly built with an allow interior, but still has a battery charger made of simple plastic.  I can't speak to the camera body though, however I'd look at the rest of the improved specs first before looking at the build quality itself.  It does appear that new D90s sell for only slightly less than new D7100s though (about $150-$200 difference).

Comment: @AJHenderson Charger is not much of concern, its the body that is as its feel light material than d90 was made up on. Is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Nikon's web site](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7100/features03.htm), there's some metal under that plastic.

> The magnesium alloy employed for the top and rear covers endows the camera with high robustness and durability, despite its compact, lightweight body. The body is effectively sealed at various locations, ensuring weather-resistance and dust-prevention performance.

Although I wasn't able to find anything as convincing regarding the D90's construction, I found a number of references to "all plastic" construction, despite its weight.

I believe in this case, you can look at the light weight of the D7100 as a bonus rather than a detriment.